# How to set value to property from attached dependency property?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview, dependency-properties

I'm trying to show selected items of treeview in textblock. This is my XAML code

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
   <Style.Triggers>
     <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
       <Setter Property="vm:HLViewModel.SelectedNode" Value="{Binding ElementName="tree",Path=SelectedItem}"/>
     </Trigger>
   </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Here is my textblock where I'm trying to show selected Item

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding myText}"/>
```

I have created attached dependencyproperty which will be set when Treeview's IsSelected property is triggered. How Can I set the value of myText in the callback function?

```
public class HLViewModel : DependencyObject
    {
        public myText{get;set;}

        public static object GetSelectedNode(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (object)obj.GetValue(SelectedNodeProperty);
        }

        public static void SetSelectedNode(DependencyObject obj, object value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(SelectedNodeProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedNodeProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("SelectedNode", typeof(object), typeof(HLViewModel), new PropertyMetadata("def",SelectedNode_changed));

        private static void SelectedNode_changed(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            // wanna set of myText property value here
        }
```

Comment: `myText` is an instance property. Do you have an instance of `HLViewModel` anywhere? Where is it? I don't see any place where you're creating one. What's a "wanna set of"?

Comment: Are you guessing that setting an attached property on your TreeViewItem will create an instance of the class where the attached property is defined? That's not the case. You are adding that property to the TreeViewItem.

Comment: @EdPlunkett This code is just for test. My goal is to get the selecteditem of treeview. TextBlock is needed to show what is selected in treeview. repeating it's just for test. I cant set myText value inside static function because we dont know instance of HLViewModel class. d as HLViewModel gives null. d comes from TreeViewItem.

Comment: Why did you use an attached property? I know WPF very well, and what you're doing makes no sense to me at all. If you want to display the selected item in the text block, just do that: `<TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=tree,Path=SelectedItem}" />`. I understand that you're testing. I understand that. But it doesn't matter. The code still doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I have observable collection type of Level class which has another observable collection type of Room in it. TreeView shows Levels as parent, rooms under it as a child. I need when i clicked levels get its child and do some calculations with room's properties and show the result at the any UI element. it doesnt matter it will be textbox, datagrid or something else.

Comment: You don't need any attached properties. First you need to stop making your viewmodels dependency objects. Use INotifyPropertyChanged instead. Do you have a main viewmodel that owns the `Levels` ObservableCollection? If you don't, you should write one. Then give that main viewmodel property `public object SelectedRoomOrLevel {...}`, and bind `<TreeView SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRoomOrLevel}" ... />`.

Comment: In SelectedRoomOrLevel's `set` block, you can check the type of the selected object (`if (value is Room) {...` etc.) and do what you need to there.

Comment: @EdPlunkett SelectedItem property is read-only and cannot be set from markup.  That's why i'm using dependency property.

Comment: Nobody's talking about setting SelectedItem. I'd forgotten you can't bind it. You can probably find attached behavior workarounds for that on Stack Overflow. You may be able to do something with the SelectedItemChanged event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the simple way to have a viewmodel use the selected item from a TreeView:

XAML:

```
    <TreeView
        x:Name="MyTreeView"
        SelectedItemChanged="MyTreeView_SelectedItemChanged"
```

Codebehind:

```
private void MyTreeView_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
{
    (DataContext as MyViewModel).SelectedRoomLevelItem = e.NewValue;
}
```

Here's a much more sophisticated way of doing the same thing. This example demonstrates how attached properties are used in WPF. Note that *setting* `TreeViewAttached.SelectedItem` will not set the selected item of the tree view -- if you want to do that, it's doable, but troublesome. All this attached property does is allow you to write bindings which *receive* the selected item from the treeview when the selection changes.

```
public static class TreeViewAttached
{
    #region TreeViewAttached.SelectedItem Attached Property
    public static Object GetSelectedItem(TreeView obj)
    {
        return (Object)obj.GetValue(SelectedItemProperty);
    }

    public static void SetSelectedItem(TreeView obj, Object value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(SelectedItemProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("SelectedItem", typeof(Object), typeof(TreeViewAttached),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null) {
                BindsTwoWayByDefault = true
            });
    #endregion TreeViewAttached.SelectedItem Attached Property

    #region TreeViewAttached.MonitorSelectedItem Attached Property
    public static bool GetMonitorSelectedItem(TreeView obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(MonitorSelectedItemProperty);
    }

    public static void SetMonitorSelectedItem(TreeView obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(MonitorSelectedItemProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MonitorSelectedItemProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("MonitorSelectedItem", typeof(bool), typeof(TreeViewAttached),
            new PropertyMetadata(false, MonitorSelectedItem_PropertyChanged));

    private static void MonitorSelectedItem_PropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((bool)e.NewValue)
        {
            (d as TreeView).SelectedItemChanged += TreeViewAttached_SelectedItemChanged;
        }
        else
        {
            (d as TreeView).SelectedItemChanged -= TreeViewAttached_SelectedItemChanged;
        }
    }

    private static void TreeViewAttached_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
    {
        SetSelectedItem(sender as TreeView, e.NewValue);
    }
    #endregion TreeViewAttached.MonitorSelectedItem Attached Property
}
```

XAML:

```
<TreeView
    local:TreeViewAttached.MonitorSelectedItem="True"
    local:TreeViewAttached.SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRoomLevelItem}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
    >
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <Label Content="{Binding HeaderText}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
<Label Content="{Binding Path=SelectedRoomLevelItem.HeaderText}" />
```

My example uses a quickie treeview item datacontext class with `Items` and `HeaderText` properties. Your use of this code will have to adapt to the particular viewmodel classes in your project.